# Autofill the 'Average' function

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of data. Each cell in the column represents a new day. So the 1st cell is for the 1st day and the Nth cell is for the Nth day. I want to add a 2nd column where the Nth cell in that column displays the average of the first N cells in the 1st column. I want to enter this formula once and then drag it down to the bottom of the column so that the entire column is 'filled' with the proper formula.

Currently, when I specify the average function like `AVERAGE(A1:A5)`, dragging that formula increases both the starting and the ending cell indices in the new filled formulas. For example, two cells down from the cell above I might have `AVERAGE(A3:A7)` when what I want is `AVERAGE(A1:A7)`.

Example:

```
Col1  __ Col2  
  7 __ __  7  
  8 __ __  7.5  
  7 __ __  7.333  
  9 __ __  7.75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following notation:

`=AVERAGE(A$1:A5)`

Copying this formula, will yield:

`=AVERAGE(A$1:A7)`

Absolute references explained:

- $A$1; Both the column and row reference are fixed.
- $A1; Only the column reference is fixed.
- A$1; Only the row reference is fixed.

Reference: [Absolute reference](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/14.3)